# JDBC Realm does not load any groups for a user [403 Forbidden]

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, glassfish, jaas, jdbcrealm

When using JDBCRealm in Glassfish as a means of authentication, you are unable to log in users as no group/role is loaded for the user. This is often only noticeable by a 403 Not Authorised message on your application.

Enabling FINEST logging for core.security shows the following:

`FINE: Login module initialized: class com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.JDBCLoginModule
FINEST: JDBC login succeeded for: user@gmail.com groups:[]
FINE: JAAS login complete.`

As you can see, groups is empty.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL,
  EMAIL varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PASSWORD longtext NOT NULL,
  SALT longtext NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  UNIQUE KEY EMAIL (EMAIL),
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

```
CREATE TABLE `users_groups` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `groupname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  KEY `FK_USERS_GROUPS_ID` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_USERS_GROUPS_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `users` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

Glassfish realm:
[image: Glassfish realm]

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by JDBCRealm looking for groups in the users_groups table that match id='user@gmail.com', when in fact it should look for groups in the users_groups table that match id=1 (the primary key of the user).

To fix, change the users_groups table foreign key to reference EMAIL:

```
CREATE TABLE `users_groups` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `groupname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  KEY `FK_USERS_GROUPS_ID` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_USERS_GROUPS_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `users` (`EMAIL`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

Or in JPA,

```
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "email"))
```

This seems a flaw in JDBCRealm, but it is known to be inflexible. 
For further debugging (and how I worked it out), look at the raw SQL commands by turning on MySQL('your database here') logging.